# how can I insert a link, in a Google Drive Document, pointing to a different Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I wan to insert, using Google Apps Script, a link in an existing Document, that opens a different document in the same domain.
I tried with HtmlService, creating a web app, with an hyperlink inside, but, the sanitization process clears the link. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You insert links into documents as paragraphs with a link property. For example

```
function myFunction() {
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var para = doc.getBody().appendParagraph("this is a link").setLinkUrl("http://www.google.com")
}
```